Configuring Libraries used in JUnit tests externally (ideally with graddle)
I am finishing work on testing/assertion library I'll be open sourcing soon that is using JUnit as a test runner for now.
There are two main parts

main assertion library that is used to make assertions/handle all the output for test results is included as a test dependency, it has many options in a config Object
an object printer library, that is used for fancy display errors, this also has many options in config Object, and is dependency of above assertion library.

Now I would like users to be able to conveniently change any option both these libraries have when they used as assertion library, ideally directly in build.graddle.kts
As of now I am using systemProperty() from within test task like this, but it is absolutely not ideal, especially for 50 or so options I have:
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    
    // setting options for lib like this works fine, DevEx terrible
    systemProperty("terminal_width", System.getProperty("terminal_width"))
    systemProperty("ignore_package_prefix", "com.github.jkavalec.")

    // JUnit itself has possiblities for config here
    // Is this the way for extra test library
    doFirst(closureOf<Any> { logger.lifecycle("${'\u200B'}\n".repeat(250)) }
}

All the functionality of both libs is configured through a singleton Object (nested) that is a part of the library, and read like in this simplified example:
object Config {
  var terminal_width = get_system_property_int_or_default("terminal_width", 80)
  var ignore_package_prefix = get_system_property_string_or_default("ignore_package_prefix", "")
  var hardcoded_example = 100
  object Nested {
    var nested_prop = 100
  }
}

Is there any good/convenient mechanism I could use that doesn't involve Env variables/Parsing JSON from Env variable?
